# How to handle an unknown number of Orders in LINQ2SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to order some data, but I have zero or more `OrderBy` clauses to apply.

As I don't know how many order clauses I have, I cannot do:

```
var myItems = dataContext.MyItems
    .OrderBy(i => i.ColumnA)
    .ThenBy(i => i.ColumnB)
    .ThenBy(i => i.ColumnC)
    .ThenBy(i => i.ColumnD)
    // etc.
```

Logically, I need something like:

```
var myItems = dataContext.MyItems;
foreach (var orderClause in myOrderClauses)
{
    myItems = myItems.SubOrderMagicallyBy(orderClause);
}
```

Obviously this is hopeless, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `myOrderClauses`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't it work with the `foreach`?
You just need to handle the special case of the first order clause:

```
IQueryable<MyItem> myItems = dataContext.MyItems;
bool first=true;
foreach (var orderClause in myOrderClauses)
{
    if(first)
    {
        myItems = myItems.OrderBy(orderClause);
        first = false;
    }
    else
        myItems = myItems.ThenBy(orderClause);
}
```

This assumes, that `myOrderClauses` is of type `IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>>`.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed my point (or, more likely, I didn't explain it very well).  You can't do a 'ThenBy' without an 'OrderBy', and a second 'OrderBy' would just reorder the whole set.  I need a way of programmatically adding more 'ThenBy's.

Comment: `OrderBy` is executed exactly once. after that, only `ThenBy`'s are used. BTW: Updated the code to include the missing `first = false;` ;-) Without it, the code makes no sense.

Comment: But `myItems = myItems.ThenBy(...` would never compile.  I'm not attempting to get my sample code to work.  It was just a logical example.

Comment: I think I am missing something. Why would `myItems = myItems.ThenBy` not compile? This would only be the case if `dataContext.MyItems` wouldn't return an `IQueryable<MyItem>` but something more specific like `ObjectQueryMyItem>`. This problem is easily solved by changing `var myItem` to `IQueryable<MyItem>`. I updated the code.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with `IOrderedQueryable<MyItem>`.  It compiled OK, but the last `ThenBy` is taking precedence over the others.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the exact code you used, because it should work.

Comment: I've created myself a simpler test with your logic (using `IOrderedEnumerable<MyItem>`) and it works great.  I'll now have a go at applying it to my real-world scenario.  Thanks very much.